# LazyColum only recompose when scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm new on jetpack compose and I'm sure that I'm missing something but I don't know what?

my State model:

```
data class ChoiceSkillsState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val errorWD: ErrorWD? = null,
    val skills: List<Skill> = emptyList(),
)
```

The Skill model:

```
@Parcelize
data class Skill(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val imageUrl: String? = null,
    var children: List<SkillChild>? = null,
) : Parcelable {
    @Parcelize
    data class SkillChild(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val imageUrl: String? = null,
        var note: Int? = null,
    ) : Parcelable

}

fun Skill.asChildNoted(): Boolean {
    if (!children.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        children!!.forEach {
            if (it.note != null) return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

on my viewModel

```
private val _state = mutableStateOf(ChoiceSkillsState())
val state: State<ChoiceSkillsState> = _state
```

On some event I update my skillList on my state : ChoiceSkillState.
When I log, my data is updated correctly but my view is not recomposed..

There is my LazyColumn:

```
@Composable
private fun LazyColumnSkills(
    skills: List<Skill>,
    onClickSkill: (skill: Skill) -> Unit,
) {

    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = MaterialTheme.spacing.medium),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(MaterialTheme.spacing.small),
    ) {

        items(
            items = skills,
        ) { skill ->
            ItemSkillParent(
                skill = skill,
                onClickSkill = onClickSkill
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is my ItemSkillParent:

```
@Composable
fun ItemSkillParent(
    skill: Skill,
    onClickSkill: (skill: Skill) -> Unit
) {

    val backgroundColor =
        if (skill.asChildNoted()) Orange
        else OrangeLight3

    val endIconRes =
        if (skill.asChildNoted()) R.drawable.ic_apple
        else R.drawable.ic_arrow_right


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.itemSkill)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .clickable { onClickSkill(skill) },

        ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 7.dp, horizontal = 10.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.itemSkillImage),

                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = skill.imageUrl),
                contentDescription = "Image skill",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(6f)
                    .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
                text = skill.name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.itemSkill
            )
            ButtonIconRoundedMini(
                iconRes = endIconRes,
                contentDesc = "Icon arrow right",
                onClick = { onClickSkill(skill) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My onClickSkill() will open a new Screen then pass result, then I will update my data with this :

```
fun updateSkill(skill: Skill) {
        val skillsUpdated = _state.value.skills
        skillsUpdated
            .filter { it.id == skill.id }
            .forEach { it.children = skill.children }

        _state.value = _state.value.copy(skills = skillsUpdated)
    }
```

As you can see, the background color and the iconResource should be changed, it's changing when only when I scroll.
Can someone explain me what's happening there ?

Comment: when you scroll it's recycled items and when item got redrawed it takes new data and shows correct state

to redraw the part runtime (without scrolling)

you should make the property as state or live data

can you show Skill object?

Comment: I add the skill object.

Comment: When you say : "you should make the property as state or live data"
I don't understand, cause my state is already typed as State.
About witch property are you thinking ?

Comment: I'm about Skill, or pass Skill As state not exactly object
Or you should make your list as mutableStateListOf () Skills

Comment: I also try to put a custom variable : val skillState = mutableStateListOf<Skill>()
then update it like :
  skillState.clear()
  skillState.addAll(skillsUpdated)

Comment: I don't see any code that should update your data, `onClickSkill` method? Please add it.

Comment: @PylypDukhov I add this informations

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `var` in class properties if you want a property update to cause recomposition.

Check out [Why is immutability important in functional programming?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming).

In this case you are updating the `children` property, but `skillsUpdated` and `_state.value.skills` are actually the same object - you can check the address, so Compose thinks it has not been changed.

After updating your `children` to `val`, you can use `copy` to update it.

```
val skillsUpdated = _state.value.skills.toMutableList()
for (i in skillsUpdated.indices) {
    if (skillsUpdated[i].id != skill.id) continue
    skillsUpdated[i] = skillsUpdated[i].copy(children = skill.children)
}
_state.value = _state.value.copy(skills = skillsUpdated.toImmutableList())
```

Note that converting a mutable list into an immutable list is also critical here, because otherwise the next time you try to update it, the list will be the same object: both `toList` and `toMutableList` return `this` when applied to a mutable list.

Comment: Thank you ! Works for me and make me understand what was happening

Comment: @MakiX You're welcome. If this solved your question, please accept it using checkmark under the votes counter and upvote (if you didn't yet)

Answer (score 0):

make your properties as state

```
 val backgroundColor by remember {
     mutableStateOf (if (skill.asChildNoted()) Orange
        else OrangeLight3)
     }
        
    val endIconRes by remember {
        mutableStateOf (if (skill.asChildNoted()) R.drawable.ic_apple else R.drawable.ic_arrow_right)
    }
```

Comment: It's not working in my case ..